# Problem with variables using a namespace at C++

Tags: c++

I am trying to write a relativity big code. The main problem, for awhile, is that there is a problem occurring when I define a dictionary.

I have a `.hh` file named `Electric.hh`. This is what is inside of it:

```
#ifndef Electric_h
#define Electric_h 1

namespace Ele{
    static constexpr double zfield = 80;
}

#endif
```

I have defined the `Ele` namespace, and the `zfield` variable, so that I can use it in another folder.

Now, the problem is: I have a file called `Tracker.cc` which uses this variable:

```
#include "Electric.hh"
...
auto hx = Ele::zfield;
std::ofstream cFile (std::to_string(hx)+".txt", std::ofstream::app);
...
```

Now, when I do `make` at the terminal so that the program runs, the first time it runs well, that is, it creates a file named `80.txt`. The problem is, now suppose I change the content inside of `Electric.hh`, so that instead of:

```
static constexpr double zfield = 80;
```

I use:

```
static constexpr double zfield = 40;
```

When I do `make` again (after do `cmake` ) on the terminal, and try to run the program again, it seems that the file `Tracker.cc` has stored the value `80`, that is, it does not create any file named `40.txt`, but creates another file named `80.txt`. I am extremely confused why. Shouldn't it forget the value `80` after I do `make`? What is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to tell in the Makefile that Tracker.cc depends on Electric.hh. So on the second `make` call nothing gets recompiled.

With gcc/clang you can create those dependencies on included files automatically, which is well worth it.

Comment: OOps. I forgot to tell, i do cmake. before write make. Shouldn't it change?

Comment: Same problem though. The default will check Tracker.o vs. Tracker.cc and recompile if the source is newer. You have to tell it bout the include.

Comment: I see. I fear that i have no idea how to edit the Makefile so as to include it :( Any tips? link recomendations?

Comment: no idea. read the cmake documentation